# Can multiple ip addreses be attached to a single network bonding device?

Tags: linux, networking, bonding

I am setting up an Ubuntu server for several hosting tasks that has 2 network cards and I have 5 ip addresses reserved for this server.

From the bonding documentation I understand that it can easily be used both as a fault tolerance and load balancing tool, but all the examples I've seen deal with only one ip address per bonding device.

What would be the correct way to bond the two network cards together and assign all of the 5 ip addresses to the single device? Can I use virtual device names like bond0:0 for that, do I set up 4 additional bond devices using the same network cards? Or is it not possible at all?

I have the server in a co-location facility and I really would not like to lose connectivity by trying something that does not work.

Comment: I don't know the exact sequence of commands, but you create the bonding device and assign it IP aliases like any other interface (I'm sure someone will be along shortly with the correct commands). You might want to check out IPMI for remote console access, your server might already support it.

Comment: I think you would use the bond0:0 type configuration - I'm not sure, which is why I'm writing a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it seems that bond0:0, bond0:1 device types are the correct way to go: http://www.christiantechsaz.com/viewtopic.php?id=139

Answer (score 0):

We have 5 IPs assigned to a single bond device.  The primary IP is bond1, the 4 secondaries are bond1:0-3.  We have eth0 configured as the master for bond0 and eth1 as master for bond1.
We are using centos 5.5.

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1  include MASTER=bond1
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond1 specifies primary IP
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond1-range0 specifies the range for the 4 secondary IPs
```

Let me know if you would like more detail from the config files.